# Why enthalpy increases when we heat a gas at constant volume

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, work

I have read many answers on stack exchange about what is the physical meaning of enthalpy, and there are some wonderful explanations.

one analogy i find very satisfying is it is the energy we need to create space for our system in our environment

but heating a gas a constant volume increases its internal energy ,but why enthalpy is increasing in that case ?

∆H=∆U+V∆p

By this formula we can see that enthalpy is increasing,but there is no pv work happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all increases in enthalpy are associated with $pv$ work. A simple example is the increase in enthalpy of a substance undergoing a phase change from a solid to a liquid at constant pressure and temperature. In this case there is heat transfer and no $pv$ work being done. The increase in enthalpy is called the latent heat of fusion.

Given a closed system and a constant volume process involving a gas we have

$$\Delta H=\Delta U+V\Delta p$$

$$\Delta U = Q-W=Q-\int pdV$$

For a constant volume process $dV=0$ and $Q=mC_{v}\Delta T$, therefore

$$\Delta H=mC_{v}\Delta T+V\Delta p$$

> I just want to know if there is a analogy, means what is the physical
> meaning of enthalpy

Enthalpy is not a fundamental property in thermodynamics, like internal energy, entropy, pressure, volume and temperature. It is a property derived from other properties, namely internal energy, pressure and volume.

Returning to your original equation

$$\Delta H=\Delta U+V\Delta p$$

For an open system $V\Delta p$ is referred to as flow work, the work involved in moving mass into and out of an open system where there is a difference in pressure that must either be overcome or that aides in moving mass into or out of the control volume. So for an open system, the utility of $H$ is that it encompasses both the change in internal energy and the flow work, into one thermodynamic property called enthalpy.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i just want to know if there is a analogy, means what is the physical meaning of enthalpy

Comment: @gurdeepsingh  I have updated my answer in response to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Enthalpy is defined as $H=U+PV$, so $$\Delta H=\Delta U+\Delta (PV)$$At constant volume, this reduces to $$\Delta H=\Delta U+V\Delta P$$